# Cepstral Example Compile Error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, g++

I'm trying to build a C++ program that incorporates Cepstral's voice synthesis features. The library was already downloaded on the machine by my predecessor but apparently he never got around to using it. The documentation is pretty much non-existent (there is a single forum that doesn't really have anything helpful). All of their included examples are in C and lack a MakeFile so I'm trying to compile them myself. The little documentation there is simply tells me I need to link to the libswift.so library.

It is a Ubuntu 12.04.5 OS and I tried this compile command

```
g++ -Wall -g tts.c -o tts -I/opt/swift/include -L/opt/swift/lib -lswift -lm
```

Which gives this error

```
/opt/swift/lib/libswift.so: undefined reference to 'sin'
/opt/swift/lib/libswift.so: undefined reference to 'exp'
/opt/swift/lib/libswift.so: undefined reference to 'cos'
/opt/swift/lib/libswift.so: undefined reference to 'log'
/opt/swift/lib/libswift.so: undefined reference to 'pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This seems to indicate that -lm is not properly linking for some reason (I also tried switching the order of m and swift for the same result).

I usually use C++ and have very little C experience. I also frequently use Makefiles or edit previous/provided Makefiles and rarely call g++ itself so it's possible I'm missing something fairly obvious. Thanks.

Comment: looks like you may need to include `cmath`

Comment: @Steephen Since the OP is building a C program, I would say `<math.h>`. Not that it matters because the errors are linker errors and not compiler errors.

Comment: Why does your "C++ program" have a `.c` extension?

Comment: As your `-lswift` is dependent on `-lm` it should come before `-lswift` can you try this `g++ -Wall -g tts.c -lm -o tts -I/opt/swift/include -L/opt/swift/lib -lswift `

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because Cepstral only has a C API (I'm trying to understand that before trying to incorporate it into the full project)

Comment: @VinayShukla Got the exact same error with the new ordering (also tried just switching the -lm and -lswift )

Comment: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/orca-list/2007-February/msg00003.html the link here answers similar query and it says you need to install `sudo apt-get install libespeak-dev` if you've not done this already

Comment: Did not have libespeak installed already but installing it (and then running ldconfig) did not change anything

Comment: You can call C functions in a C library from C++ without doing anything special (usually, might need to add `extern "C" { ... }` around the includes if the library haven't done it already). No need to try to experiment with C if you're more comfortable with C++.